# Measuring distance between two lat long points in 1000's in Python

Tags: python, latitude-longitude

I have two dataframes.

df1 has 580 unique records - with latitude and longitude information

df2 has 490000 unique records - with latitude and longitude information

I am trying to get - out of these 580 locations, how many of them are present within a radius of 400 meters of 490000 locations.

I am using the following code and it is working.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from config import conn
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import math

def distance(origin, destination):
    lat1, lon1 = origin
    lat2, lon2 = destination
    radius = 6371 *1000# km

    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
        * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c
    return d

def convertTuple(tup): 
    str =  ''.join(tup) 
    return str


df1 = pd.read_csv("/home/ubuntu/maid80.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("/home/ubuntu/iodr.csv")
ll = []
for index,rows in df2.iterrows():
        lat1 = rows['latitude']
        lon1 = rows['longitude']
        for i,r in df1.iterrows():
                k = distance((lat1,lon1),(r['latitude'],r['longitude']))
                if (k <= 400):
                        ll.append(rows['id'])
#                       print(ll)
        print(index)
        myset = set(ll)
        print(myset)
```

I am running this out of my laptop and it is taking more than 2 hours to complete all 580 iterations. My worry is the number of records in the second dataset is going to swell.

Is there a better way to do this, so that I can save time.

Comment: Do you know what is most time consuming part of your code is? If not then profile your code and try to optimize that part. Idea: can you use a simplified calculations for small distances. I'm thinking stuff like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation

Comment: @0x6d64 The forloop iteration.  Thank you for your suggestion...will check it out

Comment: What part of the for loop? Or do you have a chance to find out what part of the distance calculation is expensive?

Comment: Another idea: refactor your code to have a method that just generates information if x, y have a greater distance than 400m or not.
Then you can add fast paths where points are really far away and a simple look at only lat or only at lon tells you that they cannot be close to each other (and skip the precise calculation of the distance).
Of course check if the addition of those additional code paths really improve speed.

Comment: Can't you simply remove the second loop and do a vectorized operation?

Comment: @0x6d64 will try calculating the distance only based on latitude...the other suggestion of Small-angle is too complex for me, given the fact that I don't understand the current distance calculation I have used.

Comment: Are you able to share the data (just the lat, lon parts), so anyone interested solving this could use it for testing? What I would do is do this in two parts (1) rough-scale filtering with not-accurate formula (2) actual distance calculation with accurate formula.

Comment: By the way, the formula you are using is haversine distance and is not much accurate. For distance of 400 meters it can give errors of 1 meter or so, but I guess that it is not an issue in your case, as you need only rough filtering of points.

Comment: Thank you for all the help.  The following are the links to the files.  iodr.csv:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x1sCwm06y2yyGZFvr3dLFb9KImIQu8w9/view?usp=sharing   maid80.csv:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x1sCwm06y2yyGZFvr3dLFb9KImIQu8w9/view?usp=sharing  Since I do not have permissions to share the file, I have shared an abridged file through these links.  Instead of 490000 records, the file has 48K odd records

Comment: @Apricot The links point to the same iodr.csv file on google drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this using geopandas :

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import pyproj

df1 = pd.read_csv("/home/ubuntu/maid80.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("/home/ubuntu/iodr.csv")

gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df1['longitude'], df1['latitude']), crs=pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(4326))
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2['longitude'], df2['latitude']), crs=pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(4326))

radius = 400
for gdf in [gdf1, gdf2]:
  gdf.to_crs(pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(3857), inplace=True)

gdf1['geometry'] = gdf1['geometry'].buffer(radius)
gdf2['IS_WITHIN_400M'] = 1

gdf = gpd.sjoin(gdf1, gdf2['geometry'], how='left')
print(gdf[gdf.IS_WITHIN_400M_right==1].head())
```

---

**Some explanations :**

Geopandas will allow you to use a GeoDataFrame, on which you can "buffer" your points using a radius (really fast). The [points_from_xy](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.points_from_xy.html) function is also pretty fast and will allow you to construct those objects efficiently.

The [sjoin](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html) method (stands for spatial join) is also fast. I suspect this as something to do with algorithm including bounding boxes and/or sorting coordinates... I've had some good results using this method.

---

**Warning :**

I projected the datasets into EPSG 3857, which is global **AND** has cartesian coordinates (in meters). Regarding to any "real" project, you have to chose the projection carefully (ie chose the best "metric-system-friendly" projection in your area) to avoid any distorsion of the buffer...

Comment: +1 for using a dedicated library. Much smarter people spend probably a lot of time to make it correct and fast!

Comment: Interesting way of using sjoin! However radius of 6371 * 1000 * 400 is certainly wrong as it has dimension of m^2, but buffer accepts distance as an argument. Also using epsg 4326 seem to distort distances, and a metric projection should be used instead as you've mentioned. So it seems that this solution doesn't fit well if coordinates are distributed globally

Comment: As I said, I was not really sure of this buffer... Using it in France, I would indeed use gdf.to_crs(crs=pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(2154)) before (this system being in cartesian coordinates) before doing the buffer.

Comment: Some clues about reprojecting [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304914/python-shapely-intersection-with-buffer-in-meter) - it all depends about the real location of the dataset and the existance of a nice projection in the area ;-)

Comment: I just bumped onto [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-concave-hull-c649795c0f0f) while searching resources for another subject. The github repo seems to convert the projection to [epsg 3857](https://epsg.io/3857) (which is indeed in meters) before doing any buffer. I just edited the answer to use this projection as default.

Comment: @tgrandje Thank you for your solution.  I have been trying to use it but constantly facing error related to sjoin.  `AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'sjoin'`  I am using all these libraries for the first time, hence took time to install the dependencies.  Any thoughts / guidance would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo... (Just corrected it : you should call it by using gpd.sjoin(gdf1, gdf2))

Comment: @tgrandje  Many thanks....this works much faster.  I have accepted your answer.  Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. I will edit the answer one last time (just adding one warning about the way to choose the right projection. Espg 3857 will probably be perfect around the equatorial line, but I suspect there are far better choices in the upper/lower hemispheres.

Answer (score 1):

Sort both dataframes by latitude. This will allow not to calculate distance between pairs of points if their latitudes differ significantly. In the best case you can get speedup of 580 times.

The idea is that you loop through rows of df1 and for each row of that array find left and right indices of the second array, which latitudes are not far from that row

```
df1.sort_values(by='latitude')
df2.sort_values(by='latitude')
n1 = df1.shape[0]
n2 = df2.shape[0]
left = 0
right = 0
threshold = 400
lat_threshold = threshold / radius # latitude difference that corresponds to 400 m
for i in range(n1):
    row1 = df1.iloc[[i]]
    lat1 = row1['latitude']
    lon1 = row1['longitude']
    while left < n2 and df2.iloc[[left]]['latitude'] < lat1 - lat_threshold:
        left += 1
    while right < n2 and df2.iloc[[right]]['latitude'] < lat1 + lat_threshold:
        right += 1
    for j in range(left, right):
        row2 = df2.iloc[[j]]
        lat2 = row2['latitude']
        lon2 = row2['longitude']
        k = distance((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2))
        if (k <= threshold):
            ll.append(row2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use numpy functions for your distance function and vectorize it. That should be a lot faster:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import pandas as pd
import math

import numpy as np


def distance(origin: pd.DataFrame, lat2, lon2):
'''Measure distance not for a pair but for the whole dataframa against one point'''
    lat1 = origin['latitude']
    lon1 = origin['longitude']
    radius = 6371 * 1000  # km
    dlat = np.radians(lat2 - lat1)
    dlon = np.radians(lon2 - lon1)
    a = np.sin(dlat / 2) * np.sin(dlat / 2) + np.cos(np.radians(lat1)) \
        * np.cos(np.radians(lat2)) * np.sin(dlon / 2) * np.sin(dlon / 2)
    c = 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(a), np.sqrt(1 - a))
    d = radius * c
    return d


def main():
    df1 = pd.read_csv("/home/ubuntu/maid80.csv")
    df2 = pd.read_csv("/home/ubuntu/iodr.csv")
    ll = []
    for index, row in df2.iterrows():
        #because you can test the whole dataframe gainst one point you can remove    one loop.
        mask= distance(df1,row['latitude'],row['longitude'])<400.0
        ll.extend(df1.index[mask].to_list()) #only add points to the list where the distance is <400

    
    myset = set(ll)
    print(myset)
```

Maybe you have to switch the dataframes. I dont know which one is the one you want to collect the ids from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) with [HaversineDistance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric) metric. At first construct the tree with coordinates from the first table and then query coordinates from the second table from that tree

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree, DistanceMetric

radius = 6371 * 1000
max_distance = 400 / radius

# ensure that format of array is [latitude, longitude]
rows1 = np.deg2rad(df1[['latitude', 'longitude']].to_numpy())
rows2 = np.deg2rad(df2[['latitude', 'longitude']].to_numpy())

# haversine metric accepts latitude and longitude only in radians and returns distance
# on unit sphere
tree = BallTree(rows1, metric=DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine'))

count = tree.query_radius(rows2, r=max_distance, count_only=True)
print(df2['id'].iloc[np.nonzero(count)[0]])
```